# what is the correct way to set up a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, angular16

I have an application that uses angular as frontend, located in a frontend directory, and a django backend in a backend directory.
So basically:

```
project-root/
├── frontend/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   └── ... (other frontend files)
├── backend/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── ... (other backend files)
├── docker-compose.yml
└── ...
```

The Dockerfile I have in the frontend dir, looks like this:

```
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
    FROM node:latest as build
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install && npm run ng build


# Stage 2: Serve the Angular app with Nginx
    FROM nginx:alpine
    WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
    RUN rm -rf ./*
    COPY --from=build /app/dist .
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    EXPOSE 80
    ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

the Dockerfile in the backend dir looks like this:

```
    FROM python:3
    WORKDIR /usr/src/django-docker
    COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./
    RUN pip install -U pipenv
    RUN pipenv install --system
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 8000
    CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this :

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=localhost # Replace with your domain or localhost
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
```

I also have a nginx.config file that looks like this:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root /app/frontend/dist/frontend;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

when running `docker compose up --build` in the root directory, the servers are running, but on http://localhost:4200/user/login, I just get a nginx message, saying "welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required", instead of my login page I am expecting. What am I doing wrong?

To debug as much as possible, at first I removed all running images and containers, which I made sure are deleted by typing `docker image rm -f $(docker image ls -q)` and `docker container rm $(docker container ls -aq)`
If running the backend (`python manager.py runserver`) and frontend (`ng serve`) in two different terminals, it works, but not using the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Your first Compose file looks fine.  I might remove the `EXPOSE` and `ENTRYPOINT` lines from the frontend Dockerfile but they shouldn't make a difference.  You mention a port 4200 in the URL; what is on that port?